# How to handle a duplicate question when the original has an accepted answer that is not really acceptable?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, specific-question

[Crystal Reports: including a subreport into a grouping section?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1590241/crystal-reports-including-a-subreport-into-a-grouping-section)

Accepted answer says to link data from the main report to the parameter of the subreport.  Doesn't work.  Nothing is passed, whether I get the data from the SQL, from the "report fields", or from the group ID.

Comment on that answer alleges that you must put the subreport in the details, not in the group.  Doing that would make the answer not really an answer to the question.  It would also make it unsatisfactory for me.  The data set I have to report requires that the subreport be part of the group header.

Comment: Is the other upvoted answer suitable? (The answer being accepted doesn't mean it's correct)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply ask a question that, in your question, references the existing question but explains *why* the given answer doesn't solve your problem, specifically.

Comment: I will try that, but I predict it is flagged as a duplicate within an hour.